# How to use externaly generated lightmaps in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to the Unity engine. I use an external tool for generating very realistic lightmaps with GI in Blender but I'm not able to insert them to Unity. Blender generates .fbx file with ok uv coordinates and lightmaps but when I insert them to Unity scene its looks different (darker) than in Blender render. I guest in Unity there are no extra material channels for lightmaps just use albedo channel and I have to disable lightning for this object in scene but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me with that?

Thank you